# Как прервать работу интерпретатора php?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Один раз я вызвал PHP без аргументов и параметров, и, как задумано разработчиками php, моя консоль стала просто не отзываться на команды: я пишу команду, а она игнорируется.

Как мне нужно было выбираться из этой ситуации?

Comment: и на крестик тоже не реагирует ?

Comment: Пфф, у меня NoGUI

Comment: а Esc  на клаве есть ?

Comment: стоило ли лезть в nogui,  и пфыкать, не разбираясь в nogui?

Comment: Очень экономит память

Answer (score 11, accepted):

в случае интерпретатора *php* дистрибутивной сборки надо прервать его работу, нажав <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> или <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Еще вариантом может быть открытие еще одной сессии в другом терминале и убить процесс командой `kill`.