# для чего служит запуск интерпретатора php без опций/параметров?

Tags: php, linux

по мотивам этого вопроса: [Как прервать работу интерпретатора php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540609/178576)

если запустить интерпретатор *php* в командной строке оболочки, не передав ему никаких опций/параметров, то работа интерпретатора не завершается сразу, но ни на какой ввод нет никакой реакции. можно лишь прервать его работу, нажав <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> или <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> (если текущая строка — пустая).

если передать какую-нибудь информацию на *stdin*, то она будет просто продублирована в *stdout* и интерпретатор завершит работу:

```
$ echo -e '123\n456' | php
123
456
```

---

к сожалению, мне не удалось найти никаких упоминаний о таком способе запуска в документации.

так что же полезного можно (если вообще возможно) сделать с помощью запуска *php* без опций/параметров?

p.s. возможно, аналогичное поведение присутствует и в других операционных системах, не только в *gnu/linux*, но у меня нет возможности проверить. если да, то метку [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), вероятно, следует удалить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

будучи запущен без опций/параметров, интерпретатор *php* ожидает получения на *стандартный ввод* (*stdin*) потока байтов. после окончания потока будет предпринята попытка его интерпретации.

всё, что находится вне [тегов `<?php ... ?>`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), поступит на *стандартный вывод* (*stdout*) «как есть», а информация внутри таких тегов будет интерпретироваться как *php*-код.

при передаче потока байтов через «трубу» (*pipe*) признак окончания потока формируется автоматически, потому *php* сразу приступает к интерпретации, а вот при вводе вручную надо это сделать явно, например, нажав <kbd>enter</kbd> и <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>:

```
$ php
<?php echo "123\n"; ?>
```

и после этого получится такая картина:

```
$ php
<?php echo "123\n"; ?>
123
$
```

---

в комментариях @serxcjo подсказывает, что в *dos* и *ms/windows* вместо сочетания <kbd>ctrl+d</kbd> (интерпретируется [как конец передачи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)) надо вводить <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd>.

Comment: ctrl+d это не какая-то магическая комбинация, а символ EOF. именно поэтому PHP интерпретатор вываливается после него.

Comment: @strangeqargo, я знаю, конечно. просто старался писать как можно лаконичнее и проще.

Comment: Под DOS/Windows аналогичной комбинацией является ctrl+z

Comment: @sercxjo, спасибо, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

```
02:24:34-user/etc$ echo "123" | php 
123
02:26:07-user/etc$ echo 'echo "123"'  | php 
echo "123"
02:26:18-user/etc$ echo '<?php echo "123"; ?>'  | php 
12302:26:28-user/etc$ echo '<?php echo "123\n"; ?>'  | php 
123
02:26:21-user/etc$ php -r 'echo "123\n";' 
123

#вот тут обратите внимание на разные ошибки:
02:30:52-user/etc$ php -r 'echoq "123\n";' 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"123\n"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in Command line code on line 1

02:32:15-user/etc$ echo '<?php echoq "123\n"; ?>'  | php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"123\n"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in - on line 1
```

php-интерпретатор ждет ввода из stdin (stdin - это не клавиатура, если что), вот и все. Это стандартное поведение.

вот это вам будет интересно, я думаю: https://habrahabr.ru/post/195152/

отвечая на вопрос **"Что полезного можно сделать?"** -

все что угодно, что не поддерживается напрямую или слишком медленно сделать через bash/zsh и т.д. Посылаете строчку в php, получаете вывод.

все тоже самое, что и с perl/tcl/awk/grep/sort  и т.д. Обычная Unix-автоматизация.

UnixWay, так сказать, засунул барана, вылезла колбаса.

сортировка из командной строки, например:

```
echo '<?php $toSort = array("y","t","r","o","d","i","p"); sort($toSort); print_r($toSort); ?>'  | php 
Array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => i
    [2] => o
    [3] => p
    [4] => r
    [5] => t
    [6] => y
)
```

и да, в windows тоже все ок с этим. https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

серъезные ОС стараются поддерживать стандарт POSIX

Comment: Про "засунул барана, вылезла колбаса" я бы поспорил. Такое выражение - это, скорее, философия Windows и оно противоречит Unix Way. Философия Unix подразумевает "Делайте что-то одно, но делайте это хорошо". А это значит, чтобы получить из барана колбасу придется все делать постепенно, поэтапно (одно за другим, но хорошо). Сначала вырасти барана, потом его разделай, разработай схему мясорубки, собери ее, переработай тушу, сам разработай рецепт колбасы (кстати специи тоже придется самому вырастить) и только потом делай колбасу. И колбасу эту можно будет приготовить только определенным образом :)

Comment: strangeqargo, спасибо за напоминание про теги `<?php ... ?>`! я совсем забыл, что php интерпретирует только то, что заключено внутри них.